# Process Wrapping, Some output not displaying

Tags: c#, process

I have a small wrapping application to give a GUI to an existing console application. I'm using the `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process` class to bind to the .exe, and then using `BeginErrorReadLine()` and `BeginOutputReadLine()` to redirect any messages into the new GUI. Everything works fine except for when the console calls `Console.Write()` instead `Console.WriteLine()`, in which case the text passed to `Write` is not displayed at all. I would think that the problem is because the `WriteLine` function inserts a line break after the text, and the `Write` method does not. Is there any way to circumvent this? I can't change it from `Write` to `WriteLine` in the original command line program as `Write` is used to prompt for input.

Relevant Code:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ServerFile);
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

ServerProc = new Process();
ServerProc.StartInfo = startInfo;
ServerProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
ServerProc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ServerProc_ErrorDataReceived);
ServerProc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ServerProc_OutputDataReceived);

private void ServerProc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ConsoleTextBlock.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
        ConsoleScroll.ScrollToEnd();
    }));
}

private void ServerProc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ConsoleTextBlock.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
        ConsoleScroll.ScrollToEnd();
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is that the `Process` class is set up for convenient line-oriented event-based processing of the output of the process.  You cannot use this functionality if you need to read partial lines as they are being output.

Nevertheless, the `Process` class does give you the tools you need if you need finer-grained control over the output than the line-oriented facilities.  If you redirect the output, then `Process.StandardOutput` is a `StreamReader` and you have the whole `StreamReader` API that you can use instead of being forced to read entire lines.

For example, here is a character-by-character read of the standard output:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
int n;
while ((n = ServerProc.StandardOutput.Read()) != -1)
{
    var c = (char)n;
    var delta = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine("c = {0} (0x{1:X}) delta = {2}",
        char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ? '*' : c, n, delta);
}
```

If we run it on another console program that produces this output:

```
Console.Write("abc");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("def");
```

It produces this output:

```
c = a (0x61) delta = 44.0025
c = b (0x62) delta = 44.0025
c = c (0x63) delta = 44.0025
c = d (0x64) delta = 1109.0634
c = e (0x65) delta = 1110.0635
c = f (0x66) delta = 1110.0635
c = * (0xD) delta = 1110.0635
c = * (0xA) delta = 1110.0635
```

which shows that the `"abc"` was read one second before the rest of the line.

However, this is not convenient if you like the event-oriented I/O already provided by `Process`.  You can either:

- use the async `Stream` API
- use threads that do blocking reads

and perhaps even roll your own event-based I/O that meets your needs.

You are writing a program that is parsing another program's character-oriented output and so without full lines you will need some sort of timeout to indicate "I now satisfied that the program is done producing output for the time being."  This can be easy or hard depending on how predictable the output is.  For example, you  might be able to recognize a prompt that ends with a `"?"`.  It depends on your situation.

The point is that you'll have to use the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` `StreamReader` properties if you want something other than line-oriented I/O.

Comment: Sladkey From what I understand that the problem between using asynchronous and synchronous reading is that I would have to manually call the writing function instead of having it event based. Is this correct? Would the best solution be something like timers?

Comment: Parsing the output of a program requires writing a parser, hopefully a simple one.  It's easiest to write a parser as a thread, otherwise you will require a state machine.  You don't even need any timers at all if the output is deterministic.  The task is not a trivial one and the solution depends on your needs and your application.  The design requires cooperation with the parsing thread and that may be easiest to do using events.  Beyond that, there are many practical approaches!